# Is it possible to stream a data produced by DAQ in real time to somewhere else?

Tags: windows, user-interface, labview

Simply put, I need to take results from a DAQ and display them visually in a UI (no interaction needed) that gets information updated in real time. The DAQ I am using has an "utility" to plug into Labview, so it seems that the easiest way is to grab this data from Labview and then transmit that data to some UI using one of [these](http://www.ni.com/tutorial/10060/en/.) methods.

I am using Windows 10 (although I could boot to Ubuntu), just not sure what UI application would be best / easiest to use.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question fully but LabVIEW is often used directly as a UI for displaying data from a DAQ.

Comment: Thanks! What don't you understand? I specifically want to make a UI with custom visual graphics. This doesn't seem possible with Laview's UI

Comment: I also don't understand the question. Can you describe or show a picture (even hand drawn) of what you want the UI to look like - should it be a chart like a strip chart recorder for example, or something else? What do you need that LabVIEW's palette of front panel indicators doesn't have?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [National Instrument's tool](https://www.ni.com/es-es/shop/daqexpress.html) for DAQ UI visualization. As it is native it should be quite straightforward to use.

Comment: ahh. The problem is I"m not using NI equipment. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the DAQExpress VI in LabVIEW as @MateoRandwolf suggested. The neat thing about it is that it almost creates your first programm automatically -- besides the configuration of your NI modules.
There are just two things missing:

- a waveform chart, and
- a write to a TDMS file

Here is a snippit of a simple program doing this (the stop button is important to actually close the TMDS file before aborting the program)
[image]

If you really want to stream the data to a different device, you I suggest to use TCP/IP. There exist good examples in the documentation from which you can start (*Help* > *Find Examples...* > *Search*-tab). If you cannot accept the roughly 40ms buffer that TCP/IP has (because of shake-hands etc.), have a look on UDP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Dewesoft's DAQ systems](https://dewesoft.com/products) which use dual mode capability. They use dual data buses (EtherCAT and USB). USB for high-speed buffered data storage to the PC's SSD hard drive and the EtherCAT bus for low latency real-time stream to any 3rd party EtherCAT master.

The DAQ systems are also capable of visualising data in real-time on the display using various pre-build visual displays like recorders, XY graphs, 3D graphs, osciloscopes, FFTs, GPS, video, and numerous other...